# Prove that a similar triangle (same angles) is a scaled up version of the original triangle

Tags: geometry

Trigonometric ratios (sin, cos etc.) are based on the laws of similar triangles, so using them to answer this question would be a circular argument.

Comment: Do you remember parallel lines and transversals from elementary school?

Comment: The proof is in the various criteria for similarity of triangles (*Thales' theorem* and so on).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to use any trigonometry to solve this problem. 
Say you have two similar triangles, $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta PQR$. Let's assume that $\angle ABC \cong \angle PQR$, $\angle BCA \cong \angle QRP $ and $\angle CAB \cong \angle RPQ$, for the sake of the argument.
All you need to do is find an isometry $f$ such that $ f(A) = P $ and $\overline{BC} \parallel  \overline{QR}$. This usually involves a rotation or translation. Then, the final step is to apply the magnification $ m_{A,r} $, where the center of magnification is $A$ and the scale factor is $r = \frac{\overline{PQ}}{\overline{AB}} = \frac{\overline{QR}}{\overline{BC}}=\frac{\overline{PR}}{\overline{AC}}$.